# Problems in making database requests in airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to create tasks dynamically based on response of a database call. But when I do this the run option just don't come in Airflow, so I cant run.

Here s the code:

```
tables =  ['a','b','c'] // This works
#tables =  get_tables() // This never works

check_x = python_operator.PythonOperator(task_id="verify_loaded",
                                             python_callable = lambda: verify_loaded(tables)
                                             ) 
bridge = DummyOperator(
    task_id='bridge'
)

check_x >> bridge

for vname in tables:
    sql = ("SELECT * FROM `asd.temp.{table}` LIMIT 5".format(table= vname ))

    log.info(vname)
    materialize__bq = BigQueryOperator( sql=sql,
                                            destination_dataset_table="asd.temp." + table_prefix + vname,
                                            task_id = "materialize_" + vname,
                                            bigquery_conn_id = "bigquery_default",
                                            google_cloud_storage_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
                                            use_legacy_sql = False,
                                            write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
                                            create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                                            query_params = {},
                                            allow_large_results = True
                                          )

    bridge >> materialize__bq


 def get_tables(): 

    bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    my_query = ("SELECT table_id FROM `{project}.{dataset}.{table}` LIMIT 3;".format(
    project=project, dataset=dataset, table='__TABLES__'))

    df = bq_hook.get_pandas_df(sql=my_query, dialect='standard')
    return view_names
```

I am trying to make the commented part work but no way. The get_tables() function fetches tablenames from bigquery and I wanted to make it work dynamically this way. When I do this, I dont get the option to run AND IT LOOKS LIKE dag IS broken. Any help? Trying for a long time.

Here is screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your `get_tables()` function work outside of the DAG?

Comment: @absolutelydevastated The function works outside the dag in operator. But I needed this kind of dynamic task generation functionality based on the result of this function. If I use a list it works perfectly. This function fetches data from bigquery. I tried all possible solutions found on internet. Nothing works. I updated the thread by adding a picture of my DAG with no run option.

Comment: Unpause your DAG first. Also, try doing `airflow list_dags`. What is the exception raised?

Comment: @absolutelydevastated I tried that too. Still no use. I use airflow in google cloud composer.

Comment: So is there an error message that appears when you try to load your DAG? Because "this never works" doesn't exactly say what the problem is. Does the code not run past that line or is the output of the function something unexpected?

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Problem is whenever I use that function problem starts. If I use a hardcoded list everything is perfect and DAG works, but thats not the functionality I need. I am adding the code inside get_tables() function.

Comment: As in, I need more elaboration on the "problem", because it's not very clear what the issue is without code and description of any error message or program states.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated I updated the thread. Please check the code and screenshot above. Problem is DAG wont work if I wanted to generate dynamic operators using response from database.

Comment: So there is no error message?

Comment: @absolutelydevastated No error message at all. Thats the biggest confusion to me. I am not even able to run it because run option is missing. Please check the get_tables function in the thread. I dont know why this function call is creating problem to entire DAG.

Comment: Have you checked if your function runs *outside* of an operator? Also if you defined all your credentials inside the connections in the Airflow web UI. Try running `airflow trigger_dag <dag_id>` directly from the command line as well.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Yes I tried and this function works perfectly in the ways you said. But not in the way I described.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Or do you have any other idea to achieve this kind of dynamic task generation?

Comment: Hi, please consider closing the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57689837/3679900) since this one is more descriptive

Comment: Can you post the full DAG code? I cannot see the DAG definition. e.g. `dag = models.DAG(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the problem we must check Composer architecture

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview

[image]

The scheduler runs in GKE using the service account configured when you created the Composer instance

The web UI runs in a tenant project in App Engine using a different service account. The resources of this tenant project are hidden (you don't see the App Engine application, the Cloud SQL instance or the service account in the project resources)

When the web UI parses the DAG file, it tries to access BigQuery using the connection 'bigquery_default'. 
Checking airflow GCP `_get_credentials` source code

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py#L74

If you have not configured the connection in the airflow admin, it will use `google.auth.default` method for connecting to BigQuery using the tenant project service account. This service account doesn't have permissions to access BigQuery, it will get an unauthorised error and will not able to generate the DAG in the UI. Probably if you check in Stackdriver, you will find the BigQuery error.

On the other side, the airflow scheduler uses the service account used in Composer creation, that have the right permissions and it parses the DAG correctly

If you execute the code in your local airflow instance, as the Web UI and the Scheduler use the same service account it works as expected in both cases

The easiest solution is to add to the bigquery_default connection a Keyfile Path o Keyfile JSON to avoid using the default service account in the web UI

If you have any security concern with this solution (service account credentials will be available to anyone with access to Composer) another option is to restructure the code to execute all your code inside a PythonOperator. This PythonOperator will call get_table and then will loop executing the BigQuery commands (using a BigQueryHook instead of a BigQueryOperator). The problem of this solution is that you will have a single task instead of a task per table

Comment: Thanks for the help. But still not fix at all. Anyways I finished the task by using some trick using airflow variable and all.  Upvoted